# Hide databases in SSMS

Tags: ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Object Explorer, it shows all the databases of the connected server. But I have access permission for some of the databases.

> Is it possible to **show only accessible databases** in SSMS Object Explorer? Any settings are there?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to hide databases, so that they are not visible to all users in SSMS. Once you do that, the only people who can see the database are sysadmins and the database owner. You basically deny the "VIEW ANY DATABASE" privilege to the PUBLIC role.

```
USE MASTER
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO PUBLIC
GO
```

You can also deny the VIEW ANY DATABASE privilege for a specific login or role. For example:

```
USE MASTER
GO
GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO PUBLIC; -- turn this back on if it was off
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO USER_A;
GO
```

This is described in more detail [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2995/how-to-hide-sql-server-user-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio/).

Hope it helps.